# How to insert content of multiple columns into a new column in sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to combine the content of two columns and insert it into a new column.

But it does not work.
Example:

```
create table car(
   id bigint NOT NULL,
   manufacture character varying(255),
   number character varying(255),
   result character varying(255)
)

insert into car (result)
select concat(manufacture, ' ', number) from car
```

Result:

```
ERROR:  NULL-Value in column „id“ error Not-Null-Constraint
DETAIL:  Failed line contains (null, null, null, bmw 123).
```

How can I just update the specific row, and leave all other values as it is?

Comment: I don't understand how this is related to Java.

Comment: sorry, yes it's not of course

Comment: Try `SELECT COALESCE(col_a, '') || COALESCE(col_b, '');`

Comment: I think you actually mean to "update" rather than "insert". Update changes something about an existing row. Insert adds a new row. (assuming you want `1, bmw, 123, bmw 123`)

Comment: What's your plan for situations where the number of characters in the manufacturer and number fields is more than 255?

Comment: I can ensure this will not be the case.

Answer (score 3):

```
update car set result = concat(manufacture, ' ', number)
```